# How to delete array from a group of array?

Tags: angularjs

I have a group of arrays in `$scope.firstorder`

[Image of array group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVRhz.png).

Based on some condition e.g. array contains an element Quantity. If Quantity is `zero` I need to remove this array from the list of arrays.

How can I do that?

Here is my code:

```
for (index in $scope.firstorder)
{
var quantity = $scope.firstorder[index][0].Quantity;
if (quantity == 0)
{
    //Remove the array from $scope.firstOrder;
}

}
```

[Image of group of arrays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVRhz.png)

Comment: Show the array structure.

Comment: can you post the sample array? not the image.

Comment: My array structure is like this internally:Array[0]24: 
Array[1]0: Object
CommercialReference: "P7M18012"
Description: "
User manual:  
Maintainance guide"
ListPrice: 156.37
PurchaseQty: 1
Quantity: 1
Supplier: " AMT "
TotalCost: 156.37

Comment: So if this quantity element is zero , I want this complete array to be removed from the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use filter combined with Array functions.

```
$scope.firstorder = $scope.firstorder.filter(outerList=>{ 
      return outerList.filter(innerList=>{ 
          return innerList.Quantity === 0;
        }).length === 0; 
    });
```

If you want to modify existing array, you can "splice" after finding the index of the arrays which should be deleted.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot...it worked. I am getting the expected results.

Comment: I'm glad that I could help:)

Answer (score 0):

Use this it maybe it will help you.

```
$scope.block = $scope.block.filter(function (arr) {
    return arr.length;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that modifying structures on the time when you iterate them is a bad practice (even though possible).

I would save all the indexes affected and remove them later on (maybe not so effective, but secure).

```
var indexex = [];
for (index in $scope.firstorder) {
    var quantity = $scope.firstorder[index][0].Quantity;
    if (quantity == 0) {
       a.push(index);
    }
}
for (i in index) {
    $scope.splice(i, 1);
}
```

(I am not sure the code is perfect, I coded it directly here, check it with an IDE, but I think the idea is there)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Do you mean a.push means indexex.push(index)? and for (i in index) {
    $scope.splice(i, 1); this is where I need to give $scope.firstorder.splice?
}

Comment: I mean just store them and afterwards use the indexes to delete the arrays that you want to delete.